# webpack angular - module is not a function

Tags: angularjs, webpack

Trying to get up and running with webpack for angularjs.  Trying to setup different angular modules for each folder within /webpack  & then inject them into my main app module definition.  What am I doing wrong?

*Running into this error:*

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module mean due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module webpack due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module {"_invokeQueue":[],"_configBlocks":[],"_runBlocks":[],"requires":[],"name":"photocropper"} due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'module' is not a function, got Object
```

**entrypoint:**

```
var angular = require('angular');
ngModule = angular.module('webpack', [
    require('./webpack/photocrop/client')
])
```

**./webpack/photocrop/client/index.js**

```
var angular = require('angular');
module.exports =  angular.module('photocropper', [])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that you need to pass module name not module in the dependency

```
ngModule = angular.module('webpack', [
    require('./webpack/photocrop/client') //this is an object
])
```

You can simply require the file and just inject by name like this:

```
var firstModule = require('./webpack/photocrop/client')

ngModule = angular.module('webpack', [
    'firstModule' // this should work
])

firstModule(ngModule)
```

Comment: Yeah that makes sense.  Now that you mention that I saw somewhere else that you can do this 

`require('./webpack/photocrop/client').name`

which also works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and in my case it got solved by changing the assigment in:

```
var angular = require('angular');
```

To simply:

```
require('angular');
```

The reason is that this assigment is creating a new "angular" variable which is different than the one provided by Angular itself, hence, it doesn't have the 'module' property